# Issues with bulk insert - file could not be found

Tags: sql, sql-server, bulkinsert

I'm using this code

```
  BULK INSERT equi2022a
  FROM 'C:\Users\Someone\Documents\Processing\equi'
  WITH (FORMATFILE = 'C:\Users\someone\Desktop\formatfileequi-2.txt'
```

I'm getting this error:

> Msg 4860, Level 16, State 1, Line 125
> Cannot bulk load. The file "C:\Users\someone\Documents\QCEW Processing\equi" does not exist or you don't have file access rights.

I can clearly see that the file exists in the specified location. I have tried to include the .txt in the name but same error. Any insights as to what I could do differently?

Comment: Is that the actual file name, ie, no file type extension at all? Have you checked the SQL Server service account has access to the file?

Comment: Can you try to put file direct to c drive and change the path

Answer (score 0):

When you say you can see the file exists in the specified location, are you looking at that location from the perspective of the SQL Server process, or is it perhaps for example on your local machine at that location and you're connected to a SQL Server on a separate server via SSMS for example?

The file name/location in the BULK INSERT clause needs to be the location of the file from the perspective of the SQL Server process (i.e. on the server/machine that the SQL Server process is running on), not from the perspective of the client (i.e. SSMS) you are using (if you are for example not running SSMS on the same machine the SQL Server process is running on).